# How can I display node fields contextually in a block with terms from two separate vocabularies based on node ID?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I've got a content type that has a file field and as part of custom content type that we use to display document links. As part of that content type I have taxonomy 1 "site section" that I'm using to categorize the documents from that field so that they are displayed in specific places on the site. That part is easy.

However, the client just requested an additional level of filtering because they want more fine-grain control over what documents are displayed on what page/node. So far, the best I can figure out is that this level of filtering should be based on a new taxonomy 2 "site sub-section" that I've created that will correspond to specific nodes in the site where the documents need to be displayed.

I'm trying to figure out how I can set my contextual filter so that it will display the resulting file field document results based both on taxonomy 1, and new taxonomy 2, based on the node ID, but I can't figure out the logic to make this happen.

I'm open to other options regarding contextual filters but the node ID is the only one I can think of that would give the specificity necessary to control how and where they're displayed. But, I also cannot figure out to to declare that "when the node ID is [some node id], display nodes with taxonomy terms y and z, and only those nodes."

Is there a way to do this within Views or should I just look to create a custom PHP piece to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original goal here was to do this dynamically via contextual filters so I wouldn't need to create a bunch of individual blocks to control various displays. However, I never found a suitable solution for doing this dynamically via the contextual filters, so I ended up resorting to using different blocks with the different filters applied for each one appropriately. It makes a little more of a mess when it comes to managing blocks, but that's not that big a deal.